# Limit stretch length of bone driven by IK

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, constraints, inverse-kinematics

I am rigging a mic stand, and using stretch bones to drive the position of bones parented to the mesh. I'm using an IK on the end of the stand, to control the position of the mic arm.

[image: Mic Arm Rig]

My issue is that instead of reaching a maximum length, and then forcing the solver to use the next bone's rotation to point upward (as would happen in real life), the stretch bone continues forever, causing the mesh to effectively separate when attempting to position the IK target above a certain height.

Stretch bones are driven by the IK, and thus any of the "limit" constraints cannot affect it. Limiting the length of the IK chain to just before the stretch bone doesn't do anything, as the bone before it does not move up/down.

I'm unsure how I could force the solver to use the bone `vert angle` to drive the height when the bone `stretch bone 1` reaches a certain length.

[image: Bone animation]

Images are attached, I can provide more if required.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this issue. Could you share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: strange; https://blend-exchange.com/b/E47raJKl/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you add this driver to your ik stretch value of your stretchy bone...

[image]

you will get this:

[image]